# Picture is too big to see all views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a PizzaOverview.

[image]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="" android:id="@+id/pizza_tv" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textSize="15pt"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_iv" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
    <RatingBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_rb" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></RatingBar>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:id="@+id/pizza_date" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button android:text="close" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_bt" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

If the picture is too big the date is invisible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add scroll view to your layout or fix the size of imageview

add the scroll view to your layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="" android:id="@+id/pizza_tv" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textSize="15pt"></TextView>
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_iv" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
<RatingBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_rb" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></RatingBar>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:id="@+id/pizza_date" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="close" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_bt" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the images you supply to the activity are the correct resolution and size. 
Also make sure that you have separate layouts for separate screen size categories.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) section of the android documentation for more details on layouts and managing different screen sizes. It tells you the basics you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your image with the rating bar and the text below it in a `RelativeLayout`. Give a `marginBottom` to your `RelativeLayout` equal to the height of your `Button`. Then place your text, give it an id and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Set the `height` of the image to `fill_parent` and add attribute `android:layout:below="id_of_text"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can as the other answer states make the screen scrollable. But if your content is dynamic (and depending on device it is arguable to say you content will ALWAYS by dynamic) you should make sure the that ImageView has it's bounds set correctly.

In the source code you have:

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pizza_iv" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
```

You should instead have:

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/pizza_iv" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

The extra attribute of `weight` will make your view fill any available space along the orientation set in the bounding LinearLayout. This is dependant on the weight of other views along that orientation (as the other views have no weight value in this case it will fill all space up until the edge of your fixed views).

The extra attribute of `scaleType="centerInside"` will make your image sit in the center of the bound's you have suggested (which are the width of the screen and all available space vertically) without ever growing large enough to overlap the bounding container.

When using `ImageView` you should keep in mind that the `ImageView` is a bounding container for an Image. It can be as large or as small as possible but is only a mechanism for telling the UI where to place an image. The `scaleType` attribute is what you use to say how you want the image placing within this bounding countainer. Using `"wrap_content"` on an `ImageView` isn't effective and can lead to trouble later in the design (especially when considering different devices).